# Does a 3D print of a CAD file constitute a derivative work?

Tags: copyright, derivative-work

This came up in a comment discussion on a [news story](http://hackaday.com/2016/02/22/ask-hackaday-selling-cad-prints-that-are-not-yours/) of someone selling prints of models that were licensed CC-BY-NC-ND.

Ignoring that the seller themselve seems pretty clueless and we can disregard their defence, the question comes up in the comments: is a 3d printed object a derivative work of it's design file and if so, in what jurisdictions?

Comment: Reading the full text of your news story is fun -- the defence used is that other people violates the license, so the license is not valid

Comment: @Soren "the defense[sic] used is that other people violates the license, so the license is not valid" I don't think it's quite that simple, it's probably along the lines of "You are hosting your design on a site that makes money and is obviously commercial so it doesn't make sense that you legitimately believe it is a non-commercial license"

Comment: @Sam besides your point but "defense" is the American spelling of "defence", no need to add "[sic]".

Comment: @kasbah Huh, you learn something new every day. I think you mean "defence" is the Brittish spelling of "defense" :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the print is a derivative work in exactly the same way that a building is derivative work of the architectural and engineering plans.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the print is a derivative work. This is because it wouldn't be able to fundamentally exist without the file.