# Editing and selling 3D models licensed under CC BY-NC and CC BY-NC-ND

Tags: creative-commons, commerce

I love 3D printing and I am thinking of selling some of my prints but most of my print models are downloaded from a website. 3D models came with [Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 Unported (CC BY-NC 3.0)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/) and some are [Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs 3.0 Unported (CC BY-NC-ND 3.0)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/) .

If I edited for example this 3D model of a car, let say I put a new headlights or put a new spoiler and skirts, which of these two CC license I violate? And if I edited a model and sell them, did I violate these rules?

[image: Car model]

Comment: Selling the models for profit appears to violate the non commercial clause of both licenses.

Comment: @Brandin thank you very much for the quick reply! The CC applies to the blueprint, so other person creates the blue print and I download their work, do modifications and print the models. Still the CC rules applies to the printed model? Sorry, as I am not aware of these laws. Thanks again man!

Comment: After you modify the models, that is a derivative work so to sell your modified model you need a license from the copyright holder. But if you take a model and then produce a physical product from that model, I'm not sure how the resulting physical product would be protected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a 3D print of a CAD file constitute a derivative work?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7336/does-a-3d-print-of-a-cad-file-constitute-a-derivative-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Both of them

The physical manifestation of a 3D print model is a derivative work and so you must follow the licence. The licences are "non-commercial" - selling stuff as a business is squarely commercial.

Comment: So if the 3D print model license falls in Attribution 3.0 Unported (CC BY 3.0)  means I can sell them?